# Two functions are the same but the code works with one and not the other

Tags: differential-equations, functions, numerical-integration, replacement

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while but I honestly don't understand what is happening.

Do I have defined the same function in two different ways: one of them is hardcoded, and the other is basically a substitution of parameters in the general function. Just to be sure that I did not make any mistakes, I have verified if these two are the same by equaling one to the other and the code has returned a True, confirming that:

[image]

Afterwards, I am making a numerical integration where I use a WhenEvent[] function to stop the integration. If this event is triggered, the code saves a signal in a variable Xp, which becomes 1. Otherwise, Xp remains zero (as it is defined before the integration). The code that performs this integration, including the place where the function xxx[r] appears, is the following:

[image]

Now the problem is: if I run the code precisely as it is now, i.e., with the function xxx[r], the WhenEvent[] is triggered and it returns Xp=1. However, if I replace the function xxx[r] by the function gttBS9[r], which according to the comparison between the two is precisely the same, the WhenEvent[] is not triggered and it returns Xp=0. I honestly can not understand why this is the case, if I am missing something fundamental or if I am making a mistake somewhere, but any help is highly appreciated.

I have written here what I think is essential to understand the problem, but if you need more information about the code to be able to help, please let me know.

Thank you all and cheers!

```
PARBS9 = {\[Mu] -> 0.60876`, a[1] -> -8.38, a[2] -> -1.77, 
   a[3] -> 6.08, a[4] -> -0.204, a[5] -> 1.32, a[6] -> 0.075, 
   a[7] -> 0.0536, c[1] -> 0.269, c[2] -> 0.211, c[3] -> 0.304, 
   c[4] -> 0.29, c[5] -> 0.025, c[6] -> 0.209, c[7] -> 1.19};

grr = Exp[
   a[7] (Exp[-((1 + a[1] r + a[2] r^2)/(
        a[3] + a[4] r + a[5] r^2 + a[6] r^3))] - 1)];
gtt = Exp[
   c[7] (Exp[-((1 + c[1] r + c[2] r^2)/(
        c[3] + c[4] r + c[5] r^2 + c[6] r^3))] - 1)];
gttBS9[r_] := (gtt /. PARBS9)
xxx[r_] := E^(
  1.19` (-1 + 
     E^(-((1 + 0.269` r + 0.211` r^2)/(
      0.304` + 0.29` r + 0.025` r^2 + 0.209` r^3)))));
gttBS9[r] == xxx[r]

r0 = 1000;
rS = 2; 
rcent = 10^-10;
rend = rcent;
Xp = 0;
b0 = 1;


Sol0 = NDSolve[{\[Phi]'[
        r] == (-((b Sqrt[grr gtt]/r^2)/Sqrt[1 - (b^2 gtt)/r^2]) /. 
         PARBS9) /. b -> b0, \[Phi][r0] == 0, 
     WhenEvent[
      Abs[1 - b0^2*xxx[r]/r^2] < 10^-15, {Xp = 1, rend = r, 
       "StopIntegration"}, 
      "LocationMethod" -> "LinearInterpolation"]}, \[Phi][r], {r, 
     rcent, r0}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 15, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 15, MaxSteps -> 10000] // Quiet;
Print[Xp]
```

Comment: Please include your actual code, not just a picture of it, in your question, so that interested readers can copy and run it.

Comment: I tried to add my code but I am not sure if I did it correctly (this is my first post in here). Please let me know if it works.